# Where to report bugs for Vagrant boxes?

Tags: vagrant, bug-reporting

I have found a bug in https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/devuan2

But I do not see a place where you can file bug reports for boxes.

Is there a common place to file bugs for all boxes found on https://app.vagrantup.com ? Or do I have to hunt each individual contributor down to file a bug report for that box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxes are created by robots (https://roboxes.org) their GitHub project is https://github.com/lavabit/robox/ you can open an issue on their project.

Comment: Thank you for hunting down that individual contributor. And your answer answers the implied question. It does not, however, answer the actual question: Is there a common place for all boxes or do you have to hunt them down individually?

Comment: right there's no single place to report bug for any boxes, anyone can create an account and start uploading boxes but then it does not provide other feature, its mainly a repo for box